# Group elements visually on an isotope layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm looking into creating a huge photo wall with the help of isotope.

One of the requirements is to cluster/group the photos visually by topic. So different parts of the wall/layout would show photos/containers related to a topic/filter. Is there a simple way to handle this with isotope or maybe an additional plugin?

Here are two examples (the first one would be the preferred one)

http://psclml.lt/aJRD
http://psclml.lt/I4vo

Would appreciate thoughts and ideas. I'm also open to switch to a different plugin.

Cheers,

Pascal.